# Morphing between constant Gauss curvature surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Requesting responses on two related questions basically. First,
the Riemann sphere has umbilical points everywhere. Including this case, can a 
bending morph parameter be defined to continuously deform/morph between:
Sievert-Enneper's surface and hyper-sphere?  & Sievert-Enneper's surface and hypo-sphere?

They seem to be enclosed between two semi-infinite cuspidal edges having symmetry about two planes.
Similarly, using a bending parameter is there a way to define and morph between :
The Breather and  hyper-pseudo-sphere?  & Breather and  hypo-pseudo-sphere? They are enclosed between two semi-infinite ridges/ cuspidal edges and are 
symmetrical about two planes, so I am curious about their bending equivalence or 
a common first fundamental form.

Secondly, setting aside the Riemann sphere of umbilical points as a special 
central case, is it not possible to prove that constant positive surfaces also 
have cuspidal edges, proceeding along lines of Hilbert's proof for negative K ?